# How to exlude something from snapping without hiding it

Tags: snapping

is it possible in edit mode to exclude a mesh object from snapping without hiding it? I need it to be visible as a reference but without being snappable. I have seen others asking that in this forum but no solutions to what I am asking. Thanks

Comment: You can hold CTRL when you are moving/scaling/rotating an object to temporarily turn off snapping, but afaik there's no way to exclude a specific object when you're transforming a group of objects at a time.

Comment: Damn ... Unfortunately in my case I can't. I need to keep snapping on precisely because I need to snap to another mesh very close to the one I only want to view as a volumetric reference. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can disable *Selectable* option in *Object Properties* tab, and then use *Exclude Non-Selectable* option in *Snapping* preferences.